# Is there any way that I can ignore the character(s) sent by “Ctrl+Z” and read data from istream?

Tags: c++, istream

Here is my code.(I asked a totally different question which was unclear and marked duplicated, and due to unfamiliarity, I edit it so it looks the same as this one. Sorry for that.)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>



using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    int i;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    cout << "enter elements for v1" << endl;
    while (cin >> i) {
        v1.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << "enter elements for v2" << endl;


    //I try to ignore character(s) sent by "Ctrl+Z"
    cin.clear();
    /*cin.sync();*/
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\0x1A');
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), EOF);
    cin >> i;


    while (cin >> i) {
        v2.push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto c : v1) {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (auto c : v2) {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


}
```

I want to press 1 2 Ctrl+Z to add elements for v1, and press 3 4 Ctrl+Z to add elements for v2, but I get a empty vector v2 eventually. Is there any way I can do this? Why do the approaches I take do not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I mistook the usage of ignore,http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/,just remove all the statements contain "ignore" and I get the expected answer.